# Traditional vs Roth 401K

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-401k

I just found out that the company I work for offers 401K Roth. I am thinking of switching to 401K Roth soon. Right now I only have traditional retirement fund and no Roth. I think I have been contributing enough for my retirement but it is not diversified enough, eg traditional vs roth.

So far I have been contributing to Traditional 401K up to the yearly max amount of $18.5K.

I am aware of the tax consequences and I understand how each 401K affects taxes now and during withdrawal. I am interested in knowing other factors I am not aware of, for example mandatory withdrawal at about 70 years (for traditional 401K). Is this true for Roth 401K as well.

Is there anything else that I need to consider in making this decision?

Comment: Note that the required distribution age is the same (which is not addressed in any of the duplicates)

Comment: @DStanley: For a Roth, you can satisfy your RMD with a rollover to a Roth IRA retaining the non-taxable status, so "required distribution" is really a non-issue.